# Wikia API and Android Programming unsure of how to proceed

Tags: java, android, wiki, mediawiki-api

Hello I am trying to pull information from a page on Wikia for The Beatles and I am not sure how I would even start to go about this, I am making an app where I have a listview of The Beatles' albums and when someone clicks on the album name I want to pull the info from the Wikia to my app so I don't have to update it with new info when and if more is added at a later time.  But I cannot figure out how I would get the info from these pages.  In my app I have the layout so it has the little sub-titles like the wikia such as Tracks, Side 1, Side 2 and so on.  the wikia is located at http://beatles.wikia.com/wiki/Please_Please_Me_(album), and the subtitles give me the address of http://beatles.wikia.com/wiki/Please_Please_Me_(album)#Side1, if someone could please shed some light on how I could do this that would be a great help, I thank you in advance.

I was also thinking of just directing the app to show the mobile version of the wikia page in the app but I don't want my app to suffer from people saying "oh why is it like this when you can just go to this page in your browser? I want to have as much originality as I can, but if someone thinks this would be the best way to go please let me know your thoughts.  Thank you all again.

-Kik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wikia is based on the new Nirvana Application Framework.

1. [Request](http://api.wikia.com/wiki/Special%3aApiGate/register) an API key
2. Read the documentation from [here](http://dev.wikia.com/wiki/Nirvana)
3. Send appropriate requests to get the required information.

You can also use any of the following [client libraries](http://api.wikia.com/wiki/Client_libraries).